# Use JavaScript/Switch statement in LESS CSS

Tags: javascript, css, less

Is there a way to use JavaScript inside a LESS CSS file..?

What I am currently doing is this :

```
.f(@l) {
 float: @l;
}

#header {
 .f(left);
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is something like this.

```
.f(@l) {
   // use switch or JS function to figure out what @l is and use that.
   // for example in this case it could be "l" = left - "r" = right - "n" = none(...)
 float: @l;
}

#header {
 .f(l);
}
```

It would be cool even if we could put JS code in the less.js file and then be able to execute it from the .less file ([Source](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/dist/less-1.0.44.js))

As a sidenote, I use jQuery on this page as well, if there are any plugins/hacks using it, those are welcome as well. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds a lot like IE behaviors and expressions.

Comment: I didn't know that LESS was intended to make your CSS unreadable... ;)

Comment: LOL! :) I am trying to use zen-html/css like convention to make css shorter and easier to write. Something like `bgc` for `background-color` or `bgi` for `background-image:url()` -- CSS is too long to write sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed javascript in your lesscss files (with backticks) details here:

http://lesscss.org/#-javascript-evaluation

Edit: if that link takes you to the top of the page (as it does for me sometimes) search/scroll down to the section titled "Javascript Evaluation"

Comment: I'm aware of the backtick, but I dont' think you can go beyond one line with it. I tried implementing what I am trying to do, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @DMin a) one line can be a method call, where the method can do arbitrary things b) god, this feature is awful!!!

Comment: you'd think it couldn't be more awful, think again. I used back tick with a ternary operator(sometimes nested ;) ). I worked very unpredictably, so I decided against the whole JavaScript in .less.

Comment: Oddly your link doesn't seem to work, even though there is an element with the id `-javascript-evaluation` on the less site, it's an invalid value, so the link won't jump to that section of the page.

Comment: thanks @Web_Designer. I think the issue is that the id attribute is added dynamically, so there's a race condition between when the attribute is added and when the browser tries to scroll to it. I've added a note to my post about scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can use ternary operator in a simple expression

```
// add extra width if @miniPlayButton is true
@extraWidth: ~`('@{miniPlayButton}' == 'true' ? 1 : 0)`;

width: 2em + unit(@extraWidth, em);
```

Remember regular Javascript doesn't know about units like `em` so I find it easier (and clearer) to do something like this.

If there is a better reference for similar simple 'recipes' please post it.

I am running this server side with .NET BundleTransformer. Needed to add `javasriptEnabled` or else you get the error message "Syntax
Message: You are using JavaScript, which has been disabled."

```
  <less useNativeMinification="false" ieCompat="true" strictMath="false" strictUnits="false" dumpLineNumbers="None" 
        javascriptEnabled="true" >
    <jsEngine name="MsieJsEngine" />
  </less>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you combine [jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) with [dynamic stylesheets](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domstylesheets).

So in your example you could define something like

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="dynstyles">
.f(${l}) {
  float: ${l};
}

#header {
  .f(left);
}
</script>
<script>
document.write(
    "<style>",
    $.template("#dynstyles").tmpl({ l: "left" }),
    "</style>");
</script>
```